# How Can Serialize XML duplicate tag without attribute In C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, model-view-controller

I have an XML file that looks like this:

```
  <RECEIPT>
  <LINES>32</LINES>
  <LINE>Tst</LINE>
  <LINE> Abc</LINE>
  <LINE> Edf</LINE>
  <LINE> rrr (free of c</LINE>
  <LINE> erer!</LINE>
  <LINE>  rrr</LINE>
  <LINE>------------------------------</LINE>
  <LINE>  rr</LINE>
  <LINE>     rr</LINE>
  <LINE>------------------------------</LINE>
</RECEIPT>
```

How can I serialize this XML?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work, but... whoever designed that "xml" needs to be taken out and beaten. Metaphorically, probably.

```cs
[XmlRoot("RECEIPT")]
public class Receipt {
    [XmlElement("LINES")]
    public int LineCount {get;set;}

    [XmlElement("LINE")]
    public List<string> Lines {get;} = new List<string>();
}

...

var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Receipt));
var obj = (Receipt)ser.Deserialize(source);
```

Comment: Eventually literally...figuratively speaking.